# web api routing stops running after a few hours

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I work on asp.net mvc project with web api in visual studio.

my web api routing work so well but after a few hours stops and show under message (but mvc project work correctly):

> Server Error
>   404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are
>   looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.

how solve this problem?

**Update (More Details) :**

global.asax

```
        //register AppBase
        AppBase.Intro.Register();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        //register modules
        //this method trigger a event and run all of modules that hook to event
        ModuleActivator.AutoRegiterModules();

        //event
        var argsStarting = new Global.ApplicationStartingEventArgs();
        Global.OnApplicationStarting(argsStarting);

        //event
        var argsRouting = new Global.ApplicationRouteEventArgs();
        argsRouting.Routes = RouteTable.Routes;
        Global.OnApplicationBeforeRouting(argsRouting);

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

one my modules is "content manager api" that created in other project.

this is web api routing code:

```
    public const string RoutePerfix = "api/ContentManager/";
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        try
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: Intro.ModuleName,
            routeTemplate: RoutePerfix + "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Solved:**

I used `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to get my modules class to run them. but when app killed on IIS with next restart `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` method don't return all assemblies. so change `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` method and The problem was solved.

Comment: Please post your routing configuration here, or this question will likely be closed. Also include information such as whether or not your web API and MVC are in the same project or different ones, and your startup configuration.

Comment: Not seeing where the Web API Configuration Register method is being called at startup.

Comment: the route registration run on ModuleActivator.AutoRegiterModules() method

Comment: @MehdiRadi, Call `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)` just after registering all areas